# OWLAPI data types

Tags: owl-api

I need to get the OWLDatatype or a OWL2Datatype from the corresponding string.

For example, given `xsd:string` I would like to get the corresponding enum constant OWL2Datatype.XSD_STRING.

I tried in the following ways:

```
 - OWL2Datatype strDT = OWL2Datatype.valueOf("xsd:string")

 - OWL2Datatype strDT = OWL2Datatype.valueOf("string")

 - OWL2Datatype owl2dt = OWL2Datatype.valueOf(OWL2Datatype.XSD_STRING.getIRI().toString());
```

but they all fail throwing an exception:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class org.semanticweb.owlapi.vocab.OWL2Datatype.string` (this part changes according to what I passed - see above).

**question number 1**
The signature of the method valueOf is: `OWLDatatype.valueOf(java.lang.String name)`, with the description "Returns the enum constant of this type with the specified name".
*How can I get the names of the OWL2Datatypes?*

**question number 2**
I decided to switch to the class OWLDatatype and access the 'basic' data types using the methods of the class `OWLDataFactory`. The class offers methods for creating many different types (e.g., getDoubleOWLDatatype), except for the one corresponding to `xsd:string`.
*How can I create an OWLDatatype that corresponds to the `xsd:string` name?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question number 1, the signature is misleading: while it looks like `valueOf()` is defined by `OWL2Datatype`, it is actually defined for `Enum` - all java enumerations get it, and the string that will work for its argument is `"XSD_STRING"`, i.e., the actual name of the variable in the enumeration.

For question number 2, the problem is that xsd is a well known namespace abbreviation but it's still arbitrary - in order to translate to the full IRI for the datatype you would need a ShortFormProvider to reverse the mapping.
I can see that this would be a useful function to have but I'm not sure that it is offered at the moment. I'll raise an [issue](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/issues/56) for it.

This has been added to the OWLAPI and now there are two methods to do what you need, illustrated in this test:

```
@Test
public void shouldParseXSDSTRING() {
    // given
    OWLDataFactory df = OWLManager.getOWLDataFactory();
    String s = "xsd:string";
    // when
    XSDVocabulary v = XSDVocabulary.parseShortName(s);
    // then
    assertEquals(XSDVocabulary.STRING, v);
    assertEquals(OWL2Datatype.XSD_STRING.getDatatype(df),
            df.getOWLDatatype(v.getIRI()));
}
```

So, one way is through OWL2Datatype and an OWLDataFactory:

```
OWLDatatype string = OWL2Datatype.XSD_STRING.getDatatype(df)
```

And another is with XSDVocabulary and an OWLDataFactory:

```
OWLDatatype string = df.getOWLDatatype(XSDVocabulary.parseShortName("xsd:string"));
```